# Flutter Comparing 2 lists of objects using map and contains not working

Tags: list, dictionary, flutter, contains

I have 2 lists of Objects namely newList and oldList as shown below:

newList: `[Object{id: -LhnrmWPWN2X_cWdIAQW, title: , category: abandoned, latitude: -17.8594103, longitude: 30.9615846}, Object{id: -LhnpMHQ3l288W28qoDW, title: , category: potholes, latitude: -17.8593472, longitude: 30.9614917}]`

oldList: `[Object{id: -LhnpMHQ3l288W28qoDW, title: , category: potholes, latitude: -17.8593472, longitude: 30.9614917}]`

The problem is that using contains is not working when checking if all objects in newList are in oldList using the following code:

`newList.where((Object p) => !oldList.contains(p))
            .map((Object obj) => print('\n\n\n\ntest \n$obj'))
            .toList();`

In fact this code is returning true for both instances of the object in newList.

I expect that the code should return true for only one of the objects.

Please assist.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to check is two objects are equal or not,

In Dart by default, `==` **returns true if two objects are the same instance** the contains is the same too.

In addition, you can use the [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package to be able to compare objects.

or as [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package provides, you can do it without the package, you need to override `==` method in your object and hashCode staff.

```
class Person {
  final String name;

  const Person(this.name);

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
    identical(this, other) ||
    other is Person &&
    runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
    name == other.name;

  @override
  int get hashCode => name.hashCode;
}
```

but **I would recommend to use the [equatable](https://pub.dev/packages/equatable) package**

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';

class Person extends Equatable {
  final String name;

  Person(this.name) : super([name]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're looking for whether oldList doesn't contain the object in your code snippet. Try utilising this code.

```
newList.where((i) => oldList.contains(i)).map((obj) {
    print('${obj.id}');
    return obj;
  }).toList();
```

Here is a little [snippet](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/357b5954ce95e550b1ffad687b8c1f5a) on the workings of the code above.

Comment: Snippet doesnt open